# Add trailing-slash in URL structure

Tags: .htaccess

Can you please help me to write correctly .htaccess file. I have this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

So it rewrites from domanname.com/page.php to domanname.com/page - but if I type in domanname.com/page/ it goes to 404 page. What should I change to correct this problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a trailing slash at the end

I received many requests asking how to add a trailing slash at the end. Ignore the first snippet and insert the following code. The first four lines deal with the removal of the extension and the following, with the addition of the trailing slash and redirecting. Link to the HTML or PHP file as shown above. Don’t forget to change the code if you want it applied to an HTML file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

More info: http://alexcican.com/post/how-to-remove-php-html-htm-extensions-with-htaccess/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match a pattern whether or not there's a trailing slash, add the trailing slash followed by the regex *optional* operator `?`.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Also, added a `RewriteCond` to prevent existing directories from matching.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule to allow for an optional trailing slash:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```